# Getting Namespace error in SQLite in Store app

Tags: c#, sqlite, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am Using SQLite as database in Windows Store application using C# & XAML.

I fallowed [this link from msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx) & [samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-SQLite-in-a-Windows-c16aea77)

I tried & I got success for Sample application as How to Create Database & manipulate database, after that when I try to use in my Original Project, I am getting error in file **SQLite.cs**
This is one of the file Which will Come with **SQLite-net.**

The error is

> 'Expression' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type' D:\D
>   drive\Webview\Webview\SQLite.cs

I think the problem with my project Why Because If I try to use SQLite in new project it is working fine.
I didn't get that what is the issue.

If any one knows who are familiar with SQLite in metro apps, Please help me out.

If question is not reasonable You can ask more information about this I will try to explain

**UPDATE:**
You can get SQLite.cs file here [SQLite.cs](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs)

Error getting here Line no: 2250,2256 etc..

```
Expression _where;
List<Ordering> _orderBys;
int? _limit;
int? _offset;

BaseTableQuery _joinInner;
Expression _joinInnerKeySelector;
BaseTableQuery _joinOuter;
Expression _joinOuterKeySelector;
Expression _joinSelector;

Expression _selector;
```

Comment: Some code would be helpfull.

Comment: Do you have a namespace called 'Expression' in your code?

Comment: @Steve Yes, `using System.Linq.Expressions;`
Please check Updated Question.

Comment: I mean a namespace in your own code. Search for `namespace Expression`

Comment: @Steve  No, I don't have.

Comment: @Steve Which namespace I have to add, I checked the Sample which I am fallowing don't have any `namespace Expression `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, Finally I got the Solution from [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d3d73b1e-520d-489e-a84a-bdc04bdde81f/getting-namespace-error-in-sqlite-in-windows-store-app)

I am using `Expression` some where in my project.

```
using Expression.Blend.SampleData.SampleDataSource;
So when compiler sees 'Expression' it is being treated as namespace instead of type.
```

Thanks to [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve)